# Inconsistency of manual tramming and auto tramming/auto bed levelling

Tags: creality-ender-3, marlin, bed-leveling

I have a new Ender 3 S1 printer with CR Touch sensor (never had experience with auto levelling before) and I'm confused about how it works. Also, I updated the firmware to [Professional Firmware](https://github.com/mriscoc/Ender3V2S1).

I ran a couple of tests with different approaches and printed a two-layer square the size of the bed.

1. I do manual bed tramming using paper. Decent tolerance, all four corners of the test print have approximately the same height of ~0.45 mm
2. Then I run the tramming wizard, it touches four corners of the bed and says the back-left corner has an elevation of 0.15 mm and the front-right corner is -0.16 mm. I adjust the bed using screws until the wizard says all four corners are within ~0.03 mm and I print the same square again. The result is worse than paper levelling back-left corner is ~0.64 mm thickness and the front-right is ~0.45 mm. It even visually looks inconsistent
3. I tram the bed using paper again, print the square, and all is good. Then I built auto-leveling mesh, enabled it in starting G-code, and printed the square. Once again, the result is bad.

How it could be that manual tramming does not correspond to the probe levelling? I don't think it's a mechanics issue, since both the nozzle and the probe are sitting rigidly on the same extruder.

Here is what the mesh looks like after nice and consistent manual tramming.

[image: Photo of the Ender 3 S1's display showing the Mesh Viewer for bed leveling]